# find and replace numbers to LaTeX fractions correctly

Tags: regex, perl, replace, substitution

My Perl script takes in data and stores it as an array. The script then takes this data and converts it into a code which I can then copy into LaTeX.

Part of my data includes numbers such as 4.25, 6.5, 6.75, and I wish to do a find and replace, so that 4.25 is written as 4 1/4 when pasted into LaTeX. The user is asked for the number which is stored as `$variable`. The find and replace is done as follows:

```
$variable =~ s/\b.25\b/\\sfrac{1}{4}/;
$variable =~ s/\b.5\b/\\sfrac{1}{2}/;
$variable =~ s/\b.75\b/\\sfrac{3}{4}/;
```

What I want it to do is to replace `4.25` with the code `4\sfrac{1}{4}`, `6.5` with the code `6\sfrac{1}{2}`, and `6.75` with the code `6\sfrac{3}{4}`.

However, when running this, it replaces the .25 and .5 correctly, but .75 is replaced with `.\sfrac{1}{2}`. I'm confused about what it is doing.

I did change the code around to:

```
$variable =~ s/\b.25\b/\\sfrac{1}{4}/;
$variable =~ s/\b.75\b/\\sfrac{3}{4}/;                  
$variable =~ s/\b.5\b/\\sfrac{1}{2}/;
```

and this alleviates the above problem, but when I enter the number 5.5, it then replaces the this with `\sfrac{1}{2}.5` and not `5\sfrac{1}{2}`.

Also, if I need to convert the `@variable` to a string, how do I do this?

Comment: Your last sentence seems unrelated to the rest of this question; maybe take it out and ask a separate question, with code?

Comment: As an aside, [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) is a very convenient tool to see how a regular expression progresses through your string. That way you can easily find where your regular expression goes off the rails.

Answer (score 3):

The unescaped dot is matching any character (except newline). To match a literal dot in a regex, you want `\.` or `[.]`.

For example, `\b.5\b` matches the `75` in `0.75` because the dot can match `7`.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you shouldn't be scanning the input multiple times like that. Here's a much better solution:

```
my %map = (
   ".25" => "\\sfrac{1}{4}",
   ".5"  => "\\sfrac{1}{2}",
   ".75" => "\\sfrac{3}{4}",
);

my $alt = join "|", map quotemeta, keys %map;    
my $re = qr/\b($alt)\b/;

$var =~ s/$re/$map{$1}/g;
```